# Reading a local directory in javascript

Tags: javascript, file, directory

Do you guys have an idea on how to read a local directory 
using javascript?

Like I need to output in a list the elements of a certain directory.

I saw something like using

```
window.requestFileSystem(window.TEMPORARY, 1024*1024, onInitFs, errorHandler);
```

but in the onInitFs function this line gives out the fs.root is undefined error.

```
function onInitFs(fs) { var dirReader = fs.root.createReader();var entries = [];... }
```

Can you help me bout this? Thanks a lot.

By the way, the page will be running on IE8.

Comment: If you _know_ your page will only ever run on IE8 and you have some control over the browser security settings - in other words you're talking about an _intranet_ situation - then you should be able to use ActiveX for this. Otherwise forget it.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, `requestFileSystem` is only supported by **Chrome** with `webkitRequestFileSystem` version. Other browsers don't support it.

**IE** also has **File System Object** (FSO) which can be used.

This isn't a good practice to read file system of a user using javascript and that's a reason why it isn't supported by all browsers.

---

You should use **server-side** language to do the same instead.

Comment: You can't use server-side language to read local directories. (I'm assuming that "local" means local to the browser, i.e., client-side.)

Comment: oh sorry, what i meant is to access a directory of a server.. because i need to show the directory heirarchy in my browser,. but these files would reside in the server,.. and not on the client side like the one local to the browser..

Comment: Ah. Then I suggest you edit your question to make this clear, and provide details of the server-side technology you're using (PHP, ASP, ...?).